# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _fblas

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scipy, importerror, statsmodels

While I was **importing statsmodels.api as sm** it shows this error, how can I fix it? the same error appeared when I tried to **import scipy.stats**. And both of them worked well while doing the **import statsmodel** and **import scipy**
[ErrorDescription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xigNx.png)
[ErrorDescription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBTDt.png)

I tried to reinstall it but it didn't work.
I also tried upgrade numpy and install mkl, but still not working.[numpy+mkl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFGRS.png)
So can you please help me fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I cannot open my jupyter notebook using`jupyter lab --notebook-dir=xxxxxxx\xxx\xx` because of some **bad config** reason, so I just default my config using `jupyter notebook --generate-config`. And my jupyter back to life again.

But next I encountered another problem, my matplotlib package cannot be imported because **no module named pyparsing**. After not working with uninstall and reinstall matpltlib on my jupyter notebook panel, I went to check Anaconda prompt, by using `conda list matplotlib`, I checked all my **matplotlib** packages, uninstalled them all. And then with `conda install matplotlib`, the problem was magically fixed.

During the whole process, I don't remember when, but at some point I added my **D:\anaconda3\envs\your-own-enviroment\lib\site-packages** at which my package's location to system PATH.

AND now, `import statsmodels.api as sm` worked well, too!!! hoorayyyyyyyy!!!